# Window control receives mouse-wheel events but not scroll-bar events

Tags: winapi, scroll, mfc

I have a dialog-box (derived from `CDialog`).

Inside it, I have a window control (`CWnd`) in which I display a bitmap image.

I would like this window control to be scrollable, so I create it as follows:

```
m_Window = CreateEx(0,
                    WC_STATIC,
                    NULL,
                    WS_CHILD|WS_VSCROLL|WS_HSCROLL|SS_BITMAP,
                    {0,0,width,height},
                    this,
                    0);
```

Now, it receives mouse-wheel events, but it doesn't receive scroll-bar events (in other words, it reaches the `OnMouseWheel` handler, but it doesn't reach the `OnVScroll` and `OnHScroll` handlers).

What exactly am I missing here?

I tried adding an `SS_NOTIFY` flag to the window style when creating it, but no luck with that.

I also tried calling `EnableScrollBar(SB_BOTH,ESB_ENABLE_BOTH)`, but no luck with that either.

One thought I have in mind, is that the `WC_STATIC` class type is simply not designated for that.

I tried looking for a more suitable class type by jumping to the definition of `WC_STATIC` in file CommCtrl.h and searching for other class types (putting `#define WC_` in the search-box).

But there are too many of them, and I'm not even sure it's the right direction.

Anyone familiar with this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Use the [CScrollView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t073d82.aspx) class.

Comment: Have you called [CWnd::SetScrollInfo()](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h265xads(v=vs.71).aspx) to set the scroll range?